# Recursive Outlier Detection

Tags: r, regression, error

I have a data set where some really bad data is drowning out other outliers. I am removing the extreme outliers first and then removing other outliers recursively until no more outliers are left. Is this good stats or am I doing something terrible? If this is valid what is the method called and is there a more sophisticated way of doing it?

My methods: I am doing this by fitting a LLS model and then removing data that is outside of the standard error of the model. I do this recursively until no more outliers are present. Example code in R for two recursions would be as follows:

```
#### Recursive outlier detection

## Initializing data
x <- seq(1,10)
y <- rep(1,10)
y[5] <- 1e6
y[7] <- 10
## Fitting data and calculating error for initial set
fit1 <- lm(y~x)
err1 <- summary(fit1)$sigma
## Plotting fit and error
plot(x,y, ylim = c(-1.5*err1, 1.1e6))
abline(fit1)
lines(x, (predict(fit1) + err1), col = 'red', lty = 2)
lines(x, (predict(fit1) - err1), col = 'red', lty = 2)
```

[image]

```
## Finding outliers
ind1 <- unname(which(y > (predict(fit1) + err1) | y < (predict(fit1) - err1)))
x <- x[-ind1]
y <- y[-ind1]
## Fitting data and calculating error for recursive set
fit2 <- lm(y~x)
err2 <- summary(fit2)$sigma
## Plotting fit and error
plot(x,y, ylim = c(-1.5*err2, 11))
abline(fit2)
lines(x, (predict(fit2) + err2), col = 'red', lty = 2)
lines(x, (predict(fit2) - err2), col = 'red', lty = 2)
```

[image]

Comment: The problem of outliers hiding other outliers is called masking.  If you assume that there are multiple oultiers there are tests for detecting them. But I don't like the idea of removing outliers unless there a reason to know they are wrong.  sometimes outliers provide information about the distribution.  The distribution that the data come from may be different from what was expected.

Comment: When you fit a line like you do in the examples outliers can have a large effect on the slope of the line.  The outliers can also be masked by the fit especially when least squares is applied.  The influence function for the slope can be used to detect the outliers or leverage points. Downweighting the outliers through a robust regression may be preferable to removing them.

Comment: I know they are wrong or at least do not belong to the other values. Short explanation: The processed data comes from images taken in the dark and if there was a flicker of light, then the calculated value is very different for that image. I am expecting values between 0.00 and 0.05. The outliers are many orders of magnitude greater and differ from each other in many orders of magnitude.

Comment: In that case removing the outliers may be justified.  Do you know a range of values that flickers of light fall into?

Comment: The outlier values are all over the place apx. -50 to 50. The probability of finding them in my measurement range of 0.00 to 0.05 is very low.

Comment: What is the range of values for the correct points?

Comment: The range is 0.00 to 0.05

Comment: Then is anything below 0 or somewhat larger than 0.05 an outlier?

Comment: Ok, I see. I could try thresholding the data. But would that be a more valid method?

Comment: Add `library(robustbase); fit2 <- lmrob(y ~ x, data = data.frame(x, y), setting = "KS2014"); lines(x, predict(fit2))` to the first code block. If there really is a good linear relationship (linearity is a strong assumption), maybe that already solves your problem?

Comment: Given the nature of these data, your approach isn't bad, but implementing it with `lm` isn't the best idea.  Use a robust regression method, such as `rlm` in the `MASS` package or `lmRob` in the `robust` package.